# Combine an if statement with do while

Tags: c

I'm finishing a small game where the first task is to check whether `input > 0` or `input < 23`

```
int height;

do
{
   printf("Height: ");
   height = GetInt();
}
while((height <= 1) || (height > 23));
```

This works. When you type a value which is not according to statement, you have to type in a new one. I however also would like to include an if statement doing something like:

```
if while (condition is not true)
{
    printf("Fill in a number between 1-23!")
}
```

But cant get this working. Anybody clue on what Im doing wrong ?

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. What do you need `while` loop for? Also - it's not a c# related question.

Comment: `if while` what you mean to code here??

Comment: What is the error Message?

Comment: What's wrong with do while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write inverse:

```
int height = -1; //DEFAULT VALUE LET ME JUMP RIGHT INTO THE WHILE LOOP
while((height <= 1) || (height > 23)) {

    //IMMEDIATELY PRINT MESSAGE ABOUT ACCEPTABLE RANGE OF VALUES
    printf("Fill in a number between 1-23");  

    //READ A VALUE
    height = GetInt();
    printf("Height: ");
}
```

Comment: Great, however I'd use do..while instead of setting default value to -1.

Comment: Judging from the '!', I would assume the OP wants to print only when input is wrong, and this code will always print.

Answer (score 0):

Since `printf` always returns the number of characters printed, in this case it must be non-zero, i.e. `true`.

Therefore you can replace the `while` condition with the following:

```
do {
  /* get input */
}
while(((height <= 1) || (height > 23)) && printf("Fill in a number between 1-23\n"));
```

If the first half of the condition is `false`, the `printf` part will not be executed, and the loop exits. If the first half is `true` (`height` is outside the range), then the `printf` part will be executed and evaluated to `true`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to do this:

```
int height = -1;// Default Value
do
{
   printf("Height: ");
   height = GetInt();// get  int value
   if(!((height <= 1) || (height > 23))) // check condition
   {
    printf("Fill in a number between 1-23"); 
    break; // break loop
   }

}while((height <= 1) || (height > 23));
```

Hope this will Help You..

Comment: This duplicates the check, which is not DRY. There is a slight change any programmer changing the code later, will miss the second occurrence of the check, and only modify one of them.

Answer (score -1):

The code might be more clear when using a boolean flag.

```
int height;
bool inputCorrect;

do
{
   printf("Height: ");
   height = GetInt();
   inputCorrect = (height > 1) && (height <= 23);
   if(!inputCorrect) {
       printf("Please fill in a number between 1-23!")
   }
} while(!inputCorrect);
```

With a meaningfull name, this will be more readable when skimming code. `while(!inputCorrect)` is a nice summary of what the loop is doing.